# How to loop an AsyncTask infitinitely

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, runnable

I have the following type of application

- Pull data prices down from feed
- Process them and put them into my custom adapter
- Display the prices in a ListView (so I call setAdapter).
- Now the final stage is to repeat this infinitely perhaps at 5 second intervals.

So I have AsyncTask for handling the datadownload and on onPostExecute I update the adapter and it displays.

But how can I loop this whole activity with intervals of 5 seconds ?

Do I need to create a thread that calls this asynctask and in the thread use a loop with 5 second sleep ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Instead of using AsyncTask you should use IntentService

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `TimerTask` class and its `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method that download the data and after that update your interface using the `post()` method of a view so to avoid the AsyncTask at all. There are more way to do this, I should know because you want to download all every 5 seconds

The problem could be what to do when the datadownload fails or when it hangs for more than 5 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

```
     myTimer = new Timer();

     myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         TimerMethod();
                     }

                 }, 0, 10000); 
             }


     private void TimerMethod()
         {

             getActivity().runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);


         } 

         private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
             public void run() {


                 new AsyncTask().execute();

             }
         };
```